# How to draw u-shape distribution?

Tags: beta-distribution

I want to build a distribution as U-shape, with the x-axis of values between [1,5] continuous, and the y-axis is probability [0,1]. I am thinking of beta distribution of alpha=beta=0.5 but couldn't figure it out. Ans suggestion?

[image]

Comment: FYI, if the distribution is continuous, the y-axis isn't guaranteed to be between 0 and 1. Is it in fact a probability density function you are trying to draw, or a function that maps [0, 1] to [1, 5] with a u-shape?

Comment: Yes, the distribution is continuous.

Comment: If the range is 4, the probability density must average 0.25 per unit for the total probability to be 1. That doesn't rule out the density being above 1 per unit somewhere in the distribution.

Comment: Adding a bit to the two comments so far, the reason this is so is that, for a continuous distribution, the chance of any particular, exact value of that distribution is 0.

Comment: I don't find that anyone who hasn't independently studied analysis to the level that "probability zero" is already a familiar concept finds it a helpful concept in explanation. Conversely, what I don't see, and this surprises me, are many explanations that relate probability density to other kinds of density that people have already heard of, such as density in physics or population density in demography and geography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible densities, a beta distribution in black (though at $1$ and $5$ the densities approach $\infty$) and a parabolic distribution in red (though at $1$ and $5$ the densities approach $\frac34$) so it rather depends on what limits you want at the extremes

[image]

using R code

```
dstretchbeta <- function(x){(1/4)*dbeta((x-1)/4, 1/2, 1/2)}
dparabola <- function(x){ifelse(x < 1 | x > 5, 0, (3/16)*(x-3)^2)}
curve(dstretchbeta, from=0, to=6, ylim=c(0,1))
curve(dparabola, from=0, to=6, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!. How can I remove the lines from the curve at 1 and 5?

Comment: @ghana In the R code, using `from=1, to=5,` instead of the two `from=0, to=6,` will avoid the vertical and straight horizontal lines

Comment: Thank you @Henry. Do you know the equivalent to dbeta in Python? I tried `1/4*beta.pdf((1-x)/4,0.5,0.5,1,5)` from scipy.stats but it gives me 0 always!

Comment: @ghana It should probably be `(x-1)/4` rather than `(1-x)/4` but I do not know this part of Python, as I found early courses in it less statistician friendly than R

Comment: Thank you. It works finally `x = np.linspace(1,5,1000)
y= 1/4 * beta.pdf((x-1)/4,a=0.5,b=0.5)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.plot(x,y)`